# Hive compressed data, cluster by data and order by data performance

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a few questions regarding Hive performance.

I read somewhere online that compressed data (ORC, Snappy in particular) will result in better performance in term of reading data.
Also, if I use order by to load my data into a table, it will result in 1 big file which could reduce the read availability.
Therefore, another alternative to achieve the same effect as order by is to use cluster by which will create multiple small files.

I did an experiment on compressed data, cluster by data and order by data to see their performance.
Currently, I have 5 data nodes and 1 name node.
The data file that was loaded into each table was around 19GB+ (2 million+ records)

I created my orc snappy compression table with the following query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE orc_t (....)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION '...'
TBLPROPERTIES(orc.compress="SNAPPY")
```

I was very lost and confused when I saw the performance of each table.
The query I ran was:

```
SELECT * FROM orc_t WHERE date_format(st_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = '2017-05-20'
```

- Compressed data took 2m 45sec
- Cluster by data took 43 sec
- Order by data 43 sec

It seems like compressed data took the longest and cluster by data doesn't seem to have significant performance over order by data.

Could it be my 5 data nodes have enough reading capability that decompression actually slow the performance?
Or is my sample data not large enough?
Am I missing out something?

Could any expert please enlighten me on the above?

Comment: What are you comparing your numbers against? By the way, try ORC with Zlib compression

Comment: Hi cricket_007, good to see you again!  I'm doing a sample query which is comparing my st_time (timestamp) against a specified date (in yyyy-MM-dd format).

Comment: May I also ask why cluster by data (multiple files data) does not have significant performance over sort by data (single large file data)? Is it due to my data nodes perking its performance?

Comment: Your query doesn't have a `cluster by` or `order by`. If your hardware is capped, then yes, that has performance penalties.

Comment: Hi cricket_007, let me rephrase my question: Why multiple small data files (size of around 256MB) does not have significant performance over a single large data file (size of around 19GB+) when I perform the sample query (SELECT * FROM t WHERE date_format(st_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = '2017-05-20'; Shouldn't the multiple small data files have some performance edge over the single large data file?

Comment: It should, yes. Depending on more than simply file size. For example, what is the source of data? Hadoop can't read through smaller  Gzip files since they are not splittable

Comment: If the source of data is stored as TextInputFormat. Will the performance of the multiple small data files be better than a single large data file? I'm asking this because the performance of multiple small data files and single large file is the same. I'm unsure why is it the case.

Comment: It should be, but still depends on your hardware. Is only one map & reduce container ever allocated for the job?

Comment: When you said map & reduce container, do you mean the item under Job Browser? When I click the item I can see only 1 container, and when i click on task, i can see multiple map tasks.

Comment: I've tried to compress my data using ORC with ZLIB. When I run a sample query like SELECT * FROM t WHERE date_format(st_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = '2017-05-20'; , it took 15mins. Does the decompression usually take so long?

Comment: The combination of scanning the entire table, decompression, and converting takes long, sure... You had partitions, yes? You're not using them

Comment: I do not have any partitions as of now. If decompression takes a long time, then can I say that decompression is only to save space?

Comment: Compression saves space, yes... Never improves performance

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for the clarification! Can I ask u a question? If I only have 1 container running multiple jobs (map and reduce) does it mean I'm not doing MR in parallel?

Comment: Should be self explanatory. All data being funneled into a single process is not distributed... You need to look at your YARN UI to determine this. You should also try to use Tez or Spark instead of MR, anyway

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help you have provided. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why multiple small data files (size of around 256MB) does not have significant performance over a single large data file (size of around 19GB+) when I perform the sample query (SELECT * FROM t WHERE date_format(st_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = '2017-05-20';

You're still scanning over all the data for a single value within your data. It therefore must all be decompressed. You're also selecting all the columns, so there's no clear benefits of using ORC.

> Shouldn't the multiple small data files have some performance edge over the single large data file?

Should, but if this is not the case, it's likely that the initial input file was able to appropriately chunked into mapreduce input splits, and the disk IO isn't a blocking factor.

Snappy or Zlib compression are only saving you space, not optimizing for speed.

If you want to improve speed, partition your data for the query patterns you're going to be using often